# Rendering images in GAZEBO

Tags: gazebo-11, ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Guys,

I'm completely new to GAZEO because of a research task.
Therefor I'm focussing on the way GAZEBO is rendering and what are pros and cons of the used rendering algorithms.

I haven't found many information about it in the tutorials.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26084/rendering-images-in-gazebo/) by [morrac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36133/morrac/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo renders everything with OGRE, so maybe maybe you find your answer here https://www.ogre3d.org/

As far as I know, openGL is used as default and the UI works with QT.

---

Originally posted by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) with karma: 64 on 2021-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1